# az group delete -n $v show "ValidationError: Parameter 'resource_group_name' must conform to the following pattern"

Tags: bash, jq, azure-cli

what trouble I met:

```sh
sa@DESKTOP-WEI:~$ az group list --query "[?name != 'product'].name" | jq -c '.[]' | while read g; do     az group delete -n $g --no-wait -y;  don
e
ValidationError: Parameter 'resource_group_name' must conform to the following pattern: '^[-\\w\\._\\(\\)]+$'.
```

what I've tried :

I tried to print `$g` value,it looks like just normal string

```sh
sa@DESKTOP-WEI:~$ az group list --query "[?name != 'product'].name" | jq -c '.[]' | while read g; do     echo $g; done
"NetworkWatcherRG"
```

Comment: It should work if you change `jq -c` to `jq -r`. The problem is the souble quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why,but I changed to `for loop` to do it and it's work

```sh
sa@DESKTOP-WEI:~$ for rg in $(az group list --query "[?name != 'product'].name" | jq -r '.[]'); \
> do az group delete -n ${rg};\
> done
Are you sure you want to perform this operation? (y/n):
```

idea from :
[How to Delete Multiple Azure Resource Groups with Tags, Bash via Azure Cloud Shell, and the Azure CLI | Jon Gallant](https://blog.jongallant.com/2020/05/azure-delete-multiple-resource-groups/)